# No Turkish troops for Iraq

Tags: headline-english

Here is a sentence from a newspaper:
No Turkish troops for Iraq|at Defence talk.
What does it mean that Turkish have no troops to send Iraq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not mean that Turkish have no troops to send Iraq, it means that Turky would not send troops to Iraq.
*For* is used to refer to future movement or plans in headlines.